# Creating multiple onItemSelectedListeners

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm working on creating an android activity that has two spinners in it. I understand how to implement the `onItemSelectedListener` for one spinner, using the `onItemSelected` call back function:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOneOfTwo);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    //do things with selection...
}
```

However, what if I have multiple spinners? It seems to me that I would need a separate function, but since both spinners are set to call back `onItemSelected()` I can't take that approach. Is there any way to tell which spinner is calling the `onItemSelected()` function? Perhaps one of the parameters keys on which spinner is making the call? Then I could set its ID as the parameter for my spinner variable's ID?

I know there is a way (I'm definitely not the only one putting multiple spinners in one activity), any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: You answered your own question, you could simply use the resource ID for both the spinners and perform the actions accordingly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let 2 of your Spinners implements the same `OnItemSelectedListener` and try this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_spinner_1_id:
            // do stuffs with you spinner 1
            break;
        case R.id.your_spinner_2_id:
            // do stuffs with you spinner 2
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! thank you. So the view parameter getting passed in designates which spinner is being used... go SO!

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The `view` in the spinner will be your textView. The spinner is the `parent`. Your switch therefor would never see the spinner ID.

Comment: true, view here refers to the view that was clicked, means item of the spinner.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected(android.widget.AdapterView<?>, android.view.View, int, long)

Answer (score 2):

You can set same onItemSelected listener for all the Spinners.. like

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and the implement the action in single method using the id of the spinners

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view,
                                                  int position,long arg3) 
    {
    int id = spinner.getId();  //You can also use int id= view.getId();
    switch (id) 
    {
            case R.id.spinner1:
            // Do what you want
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
           // Your another task
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call includes which adapterview is responsible for making the call.

So just check which adapterview called your function and have code handling that respective adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example for using multiple `onItemSelectedListeners`

```
OnItemSelectedListener myListener=new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
             switch (arg2) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this,"Spinner 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this,"Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "Spinner 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use anonymous interface for more readability**

```
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```